# Perl Parse::RecDescent dont detect more text after ';'

Tags: perl, grammar

Well like the title says, I don't want to detect more text after my ';'.
Using Parse::RecDescent I have this:

```
$parser = new Parse::RecDescent (q{

    id:   /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+/
    data:   "int"|"string"|"float"
    var:data id ';'
});



while(my $line = <DATA>)
        {
          if ($parser->var($line))
          {
            print "Its a var:\t$line\n";
          }
        }
```

In my txt file I have:

> int x;gdgh

and Perl print that as "Its a var"

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You print out the input. So of course it prints the output. Your parser doesn't even produce anything worthwhile, you apparently want it to produce what it parses, but you provided no code to do that.

```
my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new(<<'__EOI__');

    {
       my %valid_types = map { $_ => 1 } qw( int string float );
    }

    start    : <skip:''> var_decl
    type     : WS IDENT { $valid_types{$item[2]} } { join '', @item[1,2] }
    var_decl : WS type WS IDENT WS ';'             { join '', @item[1..6] }

    WS       : /\s*/
    IDENT    : /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+/
__EOI__

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   if (defined( my $output = $parser->start($line) )) {
      print "$output\n";
   }
}
```

A less generic

```
my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new(<<'__EOI__');

    {
       my %valid_types = map { $_ => 1 } qw( int string float );
    }

    start    : var_decl <skip:''> /.*/ { length($item[2]) }
    type     : IDENT { $valid_types{$item[1]} }
    var_decl : type IDENT ';'

    IDENT    : /[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+/
__EOI__

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   if (defined( my $extra = $parser->var($line) )) {
      print substr($line, 0, -$extra), "\n";
   }
}
```

Neither solution have been tested.